# Google App Engine Can't Set https browser cookie between services

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies, https, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have deployed one application with two services (one frontend - React and one backend - NodeJS with Express) on Google Cloud (App Engine). We have problem setting cookies on the https only connection. With http the cookies are set. Google provides two domains one for http (http://somedomain.someid.appspot.com) and one for https (https://somedomain-dot-someid.appspot.com) NOTE the difference. We used google's wildcard certificate.

Whatever domain i set in the cookies ('https://somedomain-dot-someid.appspot.com', '.somedomain-dot-someid.appspot.com', '.appspot.com'), cookies are always set with .someid.appspot.com. I see that cookies are set when i open backend url ('someid.appspot.com') in the browser, but not in the frontend url.

I suppose the problem is that i can not set cookie on somedomain-dot-someid.appspot.com, because is not subdomain (if i use http version - http://somedomain.someid.appspot.com) it is subdomain.

How to set cookies on the https://somedomain-dot-someid.appspot.com from https://someid.appspot.com ?

Thank you

Comment: You could go https-only and not worry about the http scheme ;) Do you have a specific requirement for http?

Comment: I'm OK with this, but i can't set browser cookies on https. I'm not using custom domain. Is this could be the problem, that i can not set https cookies on .myappid.appspoit.com?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a custom domain and a different subdomain for each service.  For example, use www.example.com for your front end and service.example.com for the backend.

For each service, you should be able to set the cookie as corresponding to the domain (example.com) instead of the subdomain.  Then a cookie set on one service will be available on the other service.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm on the same way now. If this works, i'll hit you.